# Dynamic component selector for all routes in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to set up dynamic routing in Vue, driven by my backend API. The boilerplate that I've looked at suggests using a single component for all routes. A global navigation guard loads the current page data from the API and shows the correct page based on the component name sent from backend:

**router.ts**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      component: PageSelector
    }
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  loadModelByUrl(to.fullPath) // load async page data from API
  next()
})
```

**PageSelector.vue**

```
<template>
  <component v-if="model" :is="model.componentName" :key="model.guid"/>
</template>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

Are there any obvious downsides using this approach compared to using a more standard route config?

Comment: There might be no obvious downsides but I do not see any benefits either. And if there is a single route in your app - how would you distinguish bug reports (they all will use the same URL) or how could a user share the URL so that his peer can land on exactly the same screen ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I think you're missing a part of the functionality above; different pages gets loaded depending on what url you visit using `loadModelByUrl(to.fullPath)`. It's up to the backend API to decide what page to show when

Comment: Even if there are no obvious downsides - I still do not see the benefits :)

Comment: @IVOGELOV The benefit is when you want an app which content and routes are data driven from another system. This is one of the approaches to it that I haven't seen before, hence the question

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the other system simply allows you to use different route paths for any given component, depending on some arbitrary condition - e.g. depending on the current user, or actually allowing the user to define his own routes per any of the available components, right?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Right, pages and components are set up with properties in a content management system which then have their corresponding Vue component or page.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer depends on your project requirements.

With the existing setup you lose a wide array of benefits that vue router provides such as props, queries params, children routes, beforeEnter guard and many more.

Although if you have a limited of pages that backend can drive the routing, it's a very clean and dynamic implementation.

From the other side my suggestion would be to register the router page separately because you might need in future any of the router properties and not to mention that working with a team, will help them to understand how project's router pages works

Comment: Right, allthough some of the examples you mention can be achieved in other ways. Global route guard still exist and individual guards can be set on component level. Props can be passed to the component tag `<component v-bind="model.props"`. But yeah, child routes for example are a bit trickier :)

Comment: If you have a page /products/:productId and you want in your Product.vue to have access on the productId, with the current implementation how can this be done?

Comment: Good question. The product will be found using the full url and set on the `model`. If I need the product id for other calls I could just get it on `model.product.id`

Comment: Where would you use the `model.product.id`? In PageSelector.vue like this?   `<component v-if="model" :productId="model.product.id" :is="model.componentName" :key="model.guid"/>`

Comment: Yes, the model is stored in the store so I can access it without passing it as a prop.

Comment: Ok nice! What about if you have pages that can visit it only authorized users? How can you handle the beforeEnter to a page for auth and non auth users? For example, using router view you can do this: `{
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
  }` In normal vue js app you create a navigation guard in the router file which I have named it as `ifAuthenticated` and i have one more with name `ifNotAuthenticated` which indicates if the user is authenticated,hence if he can visit the page. With the current implementation how can this be done?

Comment: If the user logins, a token will be sent by each request to the backend, so authorization and authentication checks will be in the backend, similar to a navigation guard. For example, if the token is expired, the backend can return the login page model.

Comment: I see.. Well, therefore, my conclusion to be drawn is as I said it's a clean implementation but for working on this project multiple people can be tricky since for front end logic will need to read the backend codebase.

Comment: A matter of preference I guess, thanks for the discussion :)